# Can I make a URL wrap in a bibliography?

Tags: hyperref, luatex, texshop, url

I'm writing math paper using TeXShop and, in the bibliography,  I have two clickable links that extend into the border. Is there a way to make the links wrap at column 80 or something? (Elipses ...  just means there is code in between.)

```
 \documentclass{amsart}
 \usepackage{geometry} 
 \geometry{letterpaper} 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
 \begin{document}
 \title{Paper title}
 \author{my name}
 \subjclass[2020]{Primary 11D09, 11D25; Secondary 12D15}
 \maketitle
 \begin{abstract}
 ...
 \end{abstract}
 ...
 \begin{thebibliography}{10}
 \bibitem {A} \url{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369742/looking-for-references-to-pythagorean-triple-subsets}
 ...
 \bibitem {P} \url{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287070/where-is-my-error-in-trying-to-find-pythagorean-triples-with-matching-areas}
 \end{thebibliography} 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}`

Comment: By default the `\url` command (as defined by the `url` package, which is for example loaded by `hyperref`) only allows line breaks in nice positions. In particular line breaks are only allowed after certain punctuation characters like `,./:` etc. Line breaks are explicitly not allowed after `-` to avoid confusion about hyphenation. Your URLs basically contain no allowable break points after the last `/`. A first step would be to allow breaks at hyphens by loading `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}`, but this may still not result in acceptable output.

Comment: A more radical solution is to load `\usepackage{xurl}`, that package will allow line breaks in URLs at any point. That means that the URLs should not run into the margin, but you may get infelicitous line breaks like `stackexc//hange.com`.

Comment: The two links in question are just examples, but they can be shortened by dropping the complete text after the last `/`. `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369742/` links to the same page as `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369742/looking-for-references-to-pythagorean-triple-subsets`. You can make the link even shorter with the "share function", which returns `https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369742` (for me). Often it is possible to shorten a URL by cutting of unnecessary bits. If that is the case, I'd be very tempted to use the cleaned up, shorter URL in the bibliography.

Comment: @ moewe Your first suggestion worked like a charm. I can see the aesthetic value of shortening the URL to include only the "page number" the "full name" lets me know what I'm talking. about.   Thanks